# Download current html file

Tags: javascript, html

How is it possible, to let the user download the current html page? The webpage loads the text using ajax, so my code doesn't works, because it downloads the original state of the page:

```
<a href="URL_OF_THIS_PAGE" download="page.html">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<a onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#" download="page.html">Download</a>
```

How this works:

- We create an HTML anchor element with an `onclick` handler. The handler will be run when the anchor tag ("Download") is clicked.
- The anchor tag has a `download` attribute set to the value `page.html`. This tells the browser to download whatever the anchor tag's `href` attribute is pointing to and give it the filename `page.html`, rather than the default behaviour of visiting the link.
- Inside the handler the JavaScript `this.href=` changes the href attribute of the tag. This is the URL to be visited when the anchor element ("Download") is clicked. This happens on the click handler, before the click event is bubbled up to the anchor tag itself.
- The `href` attribute of an anchor tag usually has a URL in it pointing somewhere. Here we are instead setting the `href` to point to an inline value. We tell the browser what kind of value this is using the first part of the string: `'data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'`. This tells the browser that the rest of the text will be a `text/html` document with a UTF-8 charset encoding.
- Finally, the entire source code of the current document is taken as a string and appended as the value of the inline document with `encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)`. So the `href` attribute now points to an inline string representation of the HTML document itself.

To summarize: when you click the anchor tag the click handler runs and the entire document is inserted as a downloadable inline file called "page.html" that is then downloaded when the click event bubbles up to the anchor tag itself.

Comment: can u pls describe what u did? And also what command should i write on the browser console to download the current  page. pls rply

Comment: Please note any blobs (i.e. media files like `<audio>` or `<video>`), may not get saved in a replayable way - will get saved like this: `src="blob:localhost:8000/246a5b69-eff7-4c94-a572-9a969b24f6e5"` and when you try to replay: ["Not allowed to load local resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682978/getting-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-error-while-trying-to-attach-a-medi) This is *expected*, if you use `window.URL.createObjectUrl(...)`, because the [URL lifetimes are tied to the original document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: @sony To run this on the console:

```const a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = "page.html";
a.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```