# Click a URL and download it as HTML instead of visiting it

Tags: html

Newbie here.

I am learning from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) and I'm facing a problem.

The original script works fine in the [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download).

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <body>
    
        <h1>The a download attribute</h1>
    
        <p>Click on the image to download it:<p> 
        <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>   
            <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142"> 
        </a>
    
        <p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).</p>
    
    </body> 
</html>
```

But if I change `/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg` to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer.html`, it goes to the website.

But I **want it to download the webpage as HTML file when the URL is clicked**.

Something like when you right-click a link on a page and choose "download linked file" in safari.

I am using safari 13.0.3 by the way.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercept the link click.

Download the page as plain text with javascript and a CORS bypass.

Build a temporary new link and then click it.

https://jsfiddle.net/5ot02w4y/3/

```
$("a[download]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + $(this).attr("href"),
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "true"
        },
        success: function(data) {    
            var a = $('<a></a>');

            a.attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
                type: 'text/plain'
            })));

            a.attr("download", "page.html");

            $("body").append(a);

            a[0].click();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[The download attribute only works for same-origin URLs or the blog and data schemes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) The example you're trying would work if it was on the same website you're running it on. Try to change the URL to a link on the `www.w3schools.com` domain and you'll see it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like,

```
download="page you desire to download!!"
```

Please try this code in your browser, it works!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The a download attribute</h1>

<p>Click on the below link to download the file:<p>
<a href="" download="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer.html">
  click here to download
</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I copy your code to text editor and save it as xxx.html and open this html, I can see the download link. But for some reason, when I click the link, it seems it only refreshes the page. It doesn't go to stackoverflow, it doesn't download anything either

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to download some other page's HTML from your page?

I don't think you can download the linked page's HTML that simply.

When you click on that URL, some `HTTP GET` requests get sent by the browser to that website's server and the server returns the necessary htmls, stylesheets and javascript files so that your browser can show the website to you.

So, if you are trying to download the page as html, you must make that request to the server. If you don't want to visit the website while the url is clicked (Or don't want your browser to redirect to that website), you may make the `GET`  request manually from your javascript file.

But there are cross-domain issues, that won't allow you to do so. For further, you may check this question,

[Get HTML content from another site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438864/get-html-content-from-another-site)

Comment: Are you trying to download some other page's HTML from your page? -->  --> yes.

Comment: I am too junior to understand the link you gave :))

Answer (score 0):

Original answer: [Download current html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219180/download-current-html-file)

You can use download attribute and onClick javascript function to convert the page into html file and download it.

```
<a onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#" download="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer.html">Download</a>
```

Comment: Following your method, when I click the download button, safari does download a html file! But the html file corresponds to the page with the download button, not the target stackoverflow page. The downloaded html file's name is https___stackoverflow.com_questions_156686_how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer.html

Comment: So it is like the Original answer: Download current html file. But I want to download another page specified by me.

Comment: I am not sure not it seems in this case "download=" attribute only specifies the downloaded html file's name

Comment: Replace the value of download attribute with the link you want to download.